# How to change firebase real time database, data types manually?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

i have added some data manually to real time database of firebase, automatically its initiated as Long, is there any way to change it to become string manually?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store a numeric value as a string by entering it in the Firebase console, enter it with quotes around it.

So:

- If you enter `69788985`, it'll be stored as a number.
- If you enter `"69788985"`, it'll be stored as a string.

Also see this screenshot:

[image]